# Flutter GridView Lazy Load/Pagination

Tags: flutter, gridview, pagination, lazy-loading

I need some help with GridView lazy load/pagination/load more, here is my code, my stream is receiving from realtime database, i am able to get all the data, how do i add loadmore/ lazy loading, because its a large file and it freezes so i will like to add a lazyload or loadmore to avoid app crashing, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
               StreamBuilder(
                    stream: reference.orderByChild('available').equalTo(false).onValue,
                    builder: (context, snap) {
                      
                      if (snap.hasData &&
                          snap.data.snapshot.value != null
                      ) {
                        Map data = snap.data.snapshot.value;

                        itemList.clear();
                        
                        item = [];
                        data.forEach((index, data){
                         item.add(MyProductModel(id: data['sku'], name: data['name'], weight: data['weight'], imageUrl:data['imageUrl']));
                         
                          if (searchResult.isEmpty) {
                           
                            return  itemList = item;
                          } else {
                       
                            itemList = item.where((element) => element.name.toLowerCase().contains(searchResult.toLowerCase().trim())).toList();
                            
                           return itemList; //_searchList.map((contact) =>  Uiitem(contact)).toList();
                          }

                        });

                        double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/1.2;
                       

                          return Flexible(
                            child:  NotificationListener(
                              onNotification: (notificationInfo) {
                                if (notificationInfo.metrics.pixels > 50) {
                                  _sizeController.animateBack(0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
                                  _sizeControllerSmall.animateBack(10, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1200));
                                  productTopPadding = 100;

                                }
                                if (notificationInfo.metrics.pixels < 100) {
                                  _sizeController.animateBack(10, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500));
                                  _sizeControllerSmall.animateBack(0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200));
                                  productTopPadding = 0;
                                }
                                return true;
                              },
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                                child: new GridView.builder(
                                  // key:ValueKey(_forceRedraw),
                                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                  controller: _controller,
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: itemList.length ,
                                  gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2, mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                                      crossAxisSpacing: 1, childAspectRatio: childAspectRatio),
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index){

                                      return Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10 , right: 5, left: 5, bottom: 10),
                                        child: new ProductGridWidget(
                                          product: itemList[index], //productAvailable: productStatus,

                                        ),
                                      );
                                         },

                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );

                      }
                      else return Visibility(
                        visible:false,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text('No item name ${_searchQuery.text}, in $categoryText')),
                      );

                    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use (snap.connectionState == connectionState.Waiting)
Write as per shown in image. Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyXct.png

Comment: Hello Meet Patel, thanks, what about when i do a search through the list is that a solution to stop the hanging of the app when you initiate a search

Comment: Yes you can also add for search.. If you got answers please make sure to vote Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lazy loading `GridView.builder`, works fine for Flutter 3.3.7.

```dart
GridView.builder(
    // ask GridView to cache and avoid redundant callings of Futures
    cacheExtent: 100,
    
    shrinkWrap: true,
  
    itemCount: c.thumbnails.length,
  
    // Define this as you like
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      mainAxisSpacing: 0.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 0.0,
      childAspectRatio: 1.0,
    ),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

      return FutureBuilder<Image>(builder: (ctx, snap) {
        if (!snap.hasData) {
          return const SizedBox.expand(); // show nothing
        }
        if (snap.hasError) {
          return Text('An error occured ${snap.error}');
        }
        return snap.data!;
      },
      future: <YOUR THUMBNAIL FUTURE>,
    );
  }
);
```